# How to build an Excel Addin with "Microsoft Excel SDK 2013” and VS2015 community?

Tags: c++, excel, excel-formula, add-in, xll

As the title shows, I want to build a basic addin in excel which only supply a user-defined function without any GUI, just a function. How to write the framework in C++?

Does Microsoft SDK 2013 coincide with office365(office 2106) ? and vs2015?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed use the Microsoft SDK 2013 that provide the header and library files of the Excel C API to achieve it. It will work for all Excel versions (office 2016 included) and you can build it with Visual studio 2015 or any other c/c++ compilers. The SDK provides a full working example with the associated source code.

Comment: Unfortunately, as of August 2022, the Example that comes with the sdk doesn't seem to compile